# How to incorporate Git Master branch's changes into subbranches ? ( Git Branching Strategies)

Tags: git

I have the source code with below branches.

Master -> Base Project with minimal features (Lets say it has 4 features)

Branch 1 (`Customer-1`)-> Along with all master branch features and one `Customer-1` related add on feature(4 Master features + 1 X `Customer-1` Feature = 5)

Branch 2 (`Customer-2`) -> Along with all master branch features and one `customer-1` related add on feature (4 Master features + 2 X Customer-2 Features = 6)

Branch 3 (`Customer-3`) -> Along with all master branch features and one `customer-3` related add on feature (4 Master features + 3 X `Customer-3` Features = 7)

Now I have some modifications required in Master Branch's features( 4 features).

How to incorporate modified Master's features into subbranches without effecting the respective customer's features ?

Is it the correct way of branching separate customer's source codes ? If it's not the good way, please suggest me the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

If you made some new **`commits`** in your **`Master branch`** and you would like to bring those **`commits`** in your **`Feature branches`** as well, then simply **`merge`** your **`master with your feature branch`** by **`checking`** out your **`feature branch`** first and then as follows:

```
git merge master
```